# Run time error in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, runtimeexception

I am developing a chat application. Using this app users can send friend requests. once two users become friends they can message each other and visit friends profiles. When two users become friends(imagine X and Y), in a situation where X visits Y's profile and at the same time Y visits X's profile, the app get crashed.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not post screenshots. Post code and exceptions as **text**.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel ok,sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `getTimeAgo` returns `null`. As were mentioned in Exception (Line 110). 
You can debug your code and simply find a cause